# Validar el input solo si es int

Tags: python, validación

Tengo un programa que genera un numero al azar entre dos valores que ingresa el usuario, quien posteriormente debe adivinar en una determinada cantidad de intentos.

```
import random
print("introduce los valores entre los que quieres que este el numero:")

#eleccion de los valores entre los que estara el numero

while True:

  print("primer numero:")
  x = int(input())

  print("segundo numero:")
  y= int(input())

  if x>y:
    print("El primer numero debe ser menor al segundo")

  else:
    break


print(f"el numero estara entre {x} y {y} ")

numero_azar = random.randint(x,y)

intentos_realizados = 0

print("tienes 5 intentos")

while intentos_realizados <5:

  n = int(input())

  intentos_realizados = intentos_realizados + 1

  if n >numero_azar:
    print("el numero es mas bajo")

  elif n<numero_azar:
    print("el numero es mas alto")

  else:
    print("Correcto")
    break

if n == numero_azar:
 print(f"muy bien, adivinsate el numero en un total de {intentos_realizados} intentos")
else:
 print(f"el numero en el que estaba pensando era {numero_azar}")
```

Me gustaria saber como "forzar" a quien ejecute el programa a elegir dos numeros (int); para que no elija "str" lo que llevaria a un error. Esto en la primera parte del programa:

```
while True:

 print("primer numero:")
 x = int(input())

 print("segundo numero:")
 y= int(input())

 if x>y:
  print("El primer numero debe ser menor al segundo")

 else:
  break
```

Tambien si tienen alguna sugerencia sobre como optimizar el codigo o hacerlo mas "pythonic" seria genial.
Esto especialmente en esta primera parte, considero que siempre es mejor poder manejar cualquier error que el usuario pueda cometer (otro ejemplo seria que introduzca rangos de numeros no validos).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para evitar usar `try - excepts` puedes usar [isnumeric()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isnumeric#str.isnumeric) que comprueba si una cadena está compuesta de números.

```
def input_int(msg):
    while True:
        var = input(msg)
        if var.isnumeric():
            break
        print("La entrada no es un numero, reintente")
    return int(var)

x = input_int("Primer numero: ")
y = input_int("Segundo numero: ")
# .
# .
# .
# resto del código
```

Comment: Muchas gracias no conocia esa funcion!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar las sentencias **try ... except** por si la conversión falla vuelva a iniciar.

```py
    while True:
        print("primer numero:")

        try:
            x = int(input())
        except:
            continue

        print("segundo numero:")
        try:
            y = int(input())
        except:
            continue

        if x > y:
            print("El primer numero debe ser menor al segundo")
        else:
            break
```